# Filter only by existing nodes

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to get a view to have only a selective range of referenced content, (somewhat like https://www.seek.co.nz Classification filter) in its exposed filter, but not having any joy so far.

This is the scenario.

Content type of Organisation can have one or more Roles. Each Role has a field; organisation; which refers to the Org it belongs to.

I built a View listing the Roles, and can expose the organisation field belonging to the role. This gives me a select box listing all of the organisations, not just the ones that have roles attached.

Using entity references from another view, I managed to get the select box to be just those organisations with roles, but submission of the search with only an organisation selected that I know has roles would result in an empty result set, so I figured that I must be doing it incorrectly.

Any clues?